# How to create a basic web api to get data

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

Trying to create a basic web api for my database table where anyone can view my table data using a URL (JSON format?). My understanding is that I should be able to get my data by typing in table name in URL.

my database table name is `myTable` which is mapped to model class `My_Model`

**Issue:** There are no errors but when i try to type in url `https://localhost:7048/myTable/` it return page not found

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class My_Controller : Controller
{
    public My_Services _services { get; }

    public My_Controller(My_Services services)
    {
        this._services = services;
    }

    // Database Table Name = "myTable"
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<My_Model> Get()
    {

        return (IQueryable<My_Model>)_services.Get_All_Data();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My_Services class - where get all data from table

```
    public async Task<IQueryable<My_Model>> Get_All_Data()
    {
        IQueryable<My_Model> Query = from x in _context.My_DbSet
                             select x;
        return Query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that I should be able to get my data by typing in
> table name in URL.

No, this is not how it works. You should check [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0). In your example you should be able to access your data using this url: `https://localhost:7048/My_`. The reason is that your controller has the attribute `[Route("[controller]")]`. `[controller]` is a special value which means that the route should be the controller class name without the `Controller` suffix so `My_` in this case.

If you want to have access using this url: `https://localhost:7048/myTable` then you need to either change the attribute to this: `[Route("myTable")]` or to change the controller class name to `MyTableController`.

Also your `Get` method looks wrong. You should await the `_services.Get_All_Data` method instead of casting to `IQueryable<My_Model>`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IQueryable<My_Model>> Get()
{
    return await _services.Get_All_Data();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detail message!  I think i started to see how web api works now. I will also fix my conteroller ,class name so its not weird like `My_`